Why is my CPU overheating and throttling so much?
I normally use my laptop for playing old games, producing music in FL Studio and editing video, which the CPU usually stay at 80-95 degree Celsius.
But after my laptop got partly wet during a flood in my area and I got it repaired, I noticed that the CPU is throttling way severe than it was before when I run AIDA64 Stress test (before it got wet: 8% max - after repaired: 32% max) and it don’t go down to 60 degree Celsius after I exited my games or work programs like normal (it stays at 80-95 degree).
When I open my laptop and check the temps, it stay at 60 degree Celsius, but quickly goes up and hard stuck at 80-90 degree Celsius after I listen to some music on Spotify for only 15 mins (which never happened before).
The CPU is also constantly overclocking even when I have no programs open and idle at desktop (5-15% CPU Usage cuz I have an antivirus). I tried to run some light games (it only uses 15-20% CPU usage) and faced constant system freezes. I’m suspecting that the thermal paste got mixed with water but I’m not sure. Can anyone help me with this one?
My laptop is a Dell Inspiron N5110 with an i5-2430M 2,40 GHz.

You tagged this as Windows 7 which suggests the hardware is fairly old, which would also suggest, the hardware might need significant maintenance to replace the thermal paste, cleaning out all the ports, that sort of thing. The water damage cannot be easily ignored. I assume you have tried the normal solutions to improve the cooling?

@Ramhound Yes, I've tried some of the cooling improvement solutions, but it does not get any better. I've also notices that my laptop CPU temps increase very slow when I begin to stress test in AIDA64 unlike before it got water damaged (jumps straight from 60 degree Celsius to 95 degree) and also drop insanely slow or stuck at 78-80 degree Celsius (before it got wet the temps drop instantly). The voltage my laptop's receiving seems fine, the fan also seems to be working fine (i guess). The laptop is also 13 years old so I think it's the thermal paste that is causing this?

@Ramhound By the way I'm just asking this to save money, cuz I ain't gonna pay 85$ or more for the full laptop health check just to find that my thermal paste is wet.  If you want any thing like a temps screenshot or something, I could provide it to you, cuz I'm desperate and broke right now :(

What I describe is free…you asked for advice…so I gave it….sounds like your not able to investigate the situation

@Ramhound I tried... Maybe I was lazy for thorough investigations. I'll try to investigate deeper into this, thanks for the advice though.

@Ramhound Quick question I wanna ask, is it normal for CPU to overclock when I'm idle? I can't seem to find a reliable answer on the Internet.

A CPU is designed to NOT overheat even during full load. This assumes adequate cooling; in other words, you can't run a system without a heatsink and fan.

"you got your laptop repaired"  Ok, so what exactly did the repair shop do?  What parts did they replace?

My laptop was partly wet only on the left side of the laptop, so they just took my laptop apart and use a hair dryer to dry out the part of the motherboard that got wet. And it’s a free repair for me.

I have posted an answer, but please note that one main reason your question is getting close votes is that if you suspect something to be the case, you should test it. While people here may have more experience, you have your laptop in front of you, while laptops can be slightly more difficult to service than desktops, the cooling systems of laptops are usually designed to be relatively easily accessible and serviceable.

First, because your laptop is still running you're quite lucky and you can assume any physical damage is relatively limited.
Second, when a laptop is overheating and there was a clear "causing" event like in your case, your solution is pretty well defined: physically check the parts of the laptop that involve heat spreading and heat dissipation. With most laptops, these are relatively easy to access as they are intended to be relatively easy to service.
NOTE: Having a manual may be helpful for this, so go to your laptop manufacturer's support website and look for a service manual or if they have a document explaining how to replace/repair the CPU or cooler or fan, these will be helpful.
Open the laptop and access the CPU and the cooling infrastructure. Carefully remove the cooling system(s) from the CPU (these may include heatsinks, heat pipes, and/or fans). Clean the contact surfaces of any existing thermal paste and other debris or dirt or buildup. Apply new thermal paste and reinstall/reattach the cooling system(s).
NOTE: Depending on the type and model of laptop, there may be cooling systems attached to various other components, including RAM, a discrete GPU, the SSD, or other components. Physical inspection of the laptop should make it apparent whether this is the case. You should attempt to clean and repair EACH of the places where there is a cooling system, making sure there is a clean connection free of debris, buildup, or old/damaged thermal paste.
Once you've done this you can test the laptop to see whether it is still overheating.
